# Handling line continuation and escaped characters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, nuke

I am working with Python code captured from Nuke, a compositing software, which adds line continuation and escaped characters. The code typed in by the user in Nuke is as follows:

```
if nuke.frame()>1:
   ret=nuke.frame()/2
else:
   ret=nuke.frame()
```

To retrieve this code (which is stored in a node's knob in Nuke), i use the expression() method from Nuke's Python API, here's an example:

```
animation_curve = n['multiply'].animation(0)
code_string = animation_curve.expression()
```

The resulting code string is as follows:

```
[python -execlocal if\ nuke.frame()>1:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()/2\nelse:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()]
```

Then via regex pattern matching i capture only the code:

```
if\ nuke.frame()>1:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()/2\nelse:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()
```

My objective is to parse and execute this code string using the ast module in Python, taking into account the line continuation and escaped characters present. However, I am encountering difficulties due to the syntax error caused by the unexpected characters following the line continuation characters.
When I try `tree = ast.parse(code_string)` I get:

```
    if\ nuke.frame()>1:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()/2\nelse:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()
                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Note that I probably can't use .replace() to get rid of backslashes in the code because some code might actually have backslashes in it.. I also can't use exec() due to security risks.

I appreciate any insights, suggestions, or code examples that can guide me in correctly parsing and executing the Python code obtained from Nuke's animation expression. Thank you for your valuable assistance!

Comment: Can't you do `exec(my_code,replace("\ ", " "))`?

Comment: No i can't use exec (security concerns) and replacing backlashes might break some code (i have large data set i need to go through, which some actually use the \ char to line break)

Comment: `ast.walk(ast.parse("if\ 0>1:\n\ \ \ ret=\\\n1/2\nelse:\n\ \ \ ret=2".replace("\ ", " ")))` seems to work for me

Comment: How did you get to that string? It's not the same i provided in the example.
I provided "if\ nuke.frame()>1:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()/2\nelse:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()" This is the string I am getting from the expression() method after pattern matching for the code only.

Comment: The only real difference is that I included a simplified actual line continuation `\\\n`. It works as well with `print(list(ast.walk(ast.parse("if\ nuke.frame()>1:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()/2\nelse:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()".replace("\ ", " ")))))` which is the string you provided.

Comment: Oh my. this might actually work!.. I was worried that .replace("\ ", " ") would cause code that has actual line breaks to throw syntax error if the user had a space after the line break, but a space after the linebreak is illegal in python!
Thank you.. I will thinker a bit more with this tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: This seems to worked for me @JohnSG,
Please write a formal answer and I will gladly accept it as an answer if you'd like. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is that you have spaces that are escaped with backslashes `"\ "` and the `ast` package does not like them. I believe we can manually strip them out and things should hopefully work.

Try:

```py
import ast

text = "if\ nuke.frame()>1:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()/2\nelse:\n\ \ \ ret=nuke.frame()"
parser = ast.parse(text.replace("\ ", " "))  # <---- Take care of the escaped spaces
walker = ast.walk(parser)
print(list(walker))
```